# What is the default multiplayer limit for Terraria?

Tags: terraria

In the Steam version of Terraria, what is the limit of players you can have join a game and play together?

When I go to host a game, I don't really see any settings or anything that would tell me how many people can join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Server#How_to), the default max players is 8.

Comment: I scoured that darn site, and I could not for the life of me find that.  Thank you for overcoming my lack of reading ability!